# How do I get Oculus to access an External Drive through Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, oculus, oculusquest

So I've been trying to get my Oculus Quest 2 to access data from an external drive through Unity. The external drive is plugged into my Mac, and when I hit play in the Unity Editor, my code works fine. However, when built into the Oculus, I get errors saying the file isn't found.

This is my code:

```
if (!Permission.HasUserAuthorizedPermission(Permission.ExternalStorageRead))
{
    Debug.Log("Permission set?");
    Permission.RequestUserPermission(Permission.ExternalStorageRead);
}

string[] args = new string[] { "v", "*path file*" };
if (args.Length > 1 && System.IO.Directory.Exists(args[1]))
{
    directory = args[1];
    have_directory = true;
    Debug.Log("Valid directory specified!");
    if (args.Length > 2)
    {
        current_frame = int.Parse(args[2]);
    }
}
else
{
    Debug.Log("No directory found :(");
    return;
}
```

And this is my manifest file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.UnityTechnologies.com.unity.template.urpblank"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="0.1.0"
android:installLocation="auto">
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.vr.headtracking" android:version="1" android:required="true" />
<application>
<meta-data android:name="com.oculus.intent.category.VR" android:value="vr_only" />
<meta-data android:name="com.oculus.supportedDevices" android:value="quest|quest2|cambria" />
<meta-data android:name="unityplayer.SkipPermissionsDialog" android:value="false" />
<activity android:screenOrientation="landscape"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
android:configChanges="density|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|uiMode"
android:launchMode="singleTask"
android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity"
android:excludeFromRecents="true">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.INFO" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="com.oculus.permission.READ_VR_DEVICE_PARAMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.oculus.permission.SET_VR_DEVICE_PARAMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
</manifest>
```

If anyone has an ideas or workarounds, any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

The code works when I run it locally on my Mac through the Unity Editor so the file does exist at the appropriate path. The Oculus just can't find it :(

Comment: Do your debug logs (in the code your provided) also indicate/correlate that the file is not found, or are you getting exceptions that indicate the file is not found in addition to logs indicating otherwise? Have you verified that the file in question does indeed exist on the file system outside of your code (i.e. browsing to the file path manually)